# MouseEvent getPoint(), Math.asin(), and coordinates problems

Tags: java, math, mouseevent, line, point

I'm having trouble with the MouseEvent getPoint() method, the Math.asin() method, and just in general with coordinates. I am trying to create multiple objects called "Laser" to get fired from the "playerRobot". A rectangle is created around the playerRobot and the tempR.getCenterX and tempR.getCenterY are used to construct the point at the center of the playerRobot's location. The MouseEvent getPoint() is used to get the location of the mouse relative to the focused component. In the Laser class, two methods called getPointX(int y) and getPointY(int x) return a point with the respective x and y values corresponding to the given y or x value. I.e., getPointX(int y) returns a point with y and its corresponding x value. These methods do this by finding the linear equation between the given point of the playerRobot and the mouse. Then, the Laser is supposed to be drawn at the playerRobot point and redrawn to follow its linear equation to the mouse's point and continue on the linear equation until it reaches the borders of the component. However, depending on the angle at which the Laser is fired, it does not seem to always do this. Also, sometimes the Laser does not fire at all, sometimes it fires in the wrong direction or at the wrong angle, and sometimes it is longer than 50 pixels, which is always supposed to be the length of the Laser.

TL;DR: The Laser does not always fire from the playerRobot and does not always follow the linear line to the mouse's point, sometimes fires in the wrong direction or at the wrong angle, and sometimes is longer than 50 pixels.

Here is the code in the GameCanvas class that creates a new Laser object, followed by the code in the Laser class:

GameCanvas:

```
package application;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameCanvas extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener, MouseListener {

    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    double x = 0, y = 0, velX = 0, velY = 0;
    boolean keyPress = false;
    int code = 0;
    long time = 1;
    int currAIDelete = -1;
    int currPlayerDelete = -1;
    Graphics gr;
    Point mousePoint = new Point();
    AffineTransform oldTransform = new AffineTransform();

    public GameCanvas() {
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        if(GameGUI.startScreen != null) {x = GameGUI.startScreen.imageLocationList.get(4).x; y = GameGUI.startScreen.imageLocationList.get(4).y; velX = 0; velY = 0;}
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        gr = g;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if(!GameGUI.getGameOver()) {
            if(g2 != null) {
                g2.drawImage(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(GameGUI.startScreen.imageList.get(7))).getImage(), (int) (x + 0.5), (int) (y + 0.5 + 64), GameGUI.startScreen.DEFAULT_SCALED_IMAGE_SIZE_LIST.get(7).width, GameGUI.startScreen.DEFAULT_SCALED_IMAGE_SIZE_LIST.get(7).height, this);
                g2.drawImage(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(GameGUI.startScreen.imageList.get(6))).getImage(), (int) (x + 0.5), (int) (y + 0.5 + 16), GameGUI.startScreen.DEFAULT_SCALED_IMAGE_SIZE_LIST.get(6).width, GameGUI.startScreen.DEFAULT_SCALED_IMAGE_SIZE_LIST.get(6).height, this);
                g2.drawImage(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(GameGUI.startScreen.imageList.get(5))).getImage(), (int) (x + 0.5), (int) (y + 0.5 + 16), GameGUI.startScreen.DEFAULT_SCALED_IMAGE_SIZE_LIST.get(5).width, GameGUI.startScreen.DEFAULT_SCALED_IMAGE_SIZE_LIST.get(5).height, this);
                g2.drawImage(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(GameGUI.startScreen.imageList.get(4))).getImage(), (int) (x + 0.5), (int) (y + 0.5), GameGUI.startScreen.DEFAULT_SCALED_IMAGE_SIZE_LIST.get(4).width, GameGUI.startScreen.DEFAULT_SCALED_IMAGE_SIZE_LIST.get(4).height, this);
                for(int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
                    g2.drawImage(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(GameGUI.startScreen.imageList.get(i))).getImage(), GameGUI.startScreen.imageLocationList.get(i).x, GameGUI.startScreen.imageLocationList.get(i).y, GameGUI.startScreen.DEFAULT_SCALED_IMAGE_SIZE_LIST.get(i).width, GameGUI.startScreen.DEFAULT_SCALED_IMAGE_SIZE_LIST.get(i).height, this);
                Color tempColor = g2.getColor();
                g2.setColor(tempColor);
                GameGUI.startScreen.healthBar();
                tempColor = g2.getColor();
                GameGUI.startScreen.healthBarGlyphVector = new Font("Tahoma", 0, 11).createGlyphVector(new FontRenderContext(null, true, false), String.valueOf(GameGUI.startScreen.playerHealth));
                g2.setColor(GameGUI.startScreen.playerHealthBarColor);
                g2.drawGlyphVector(GameGUI.startScreen.healthBarGlyphVector, (int) (x + 40 - GameGUI.startScreen.healthBarGlyphVector.getNumGlyphs() * (double) GameGUI.startScreen.healthBarGlyphVector.getFont().getSize() / 2 + 0.5), (long) (y + 0.5) - 20);
                GameGUI.startScreen.playerHealthBar.setLocation((int) (x + 0.5), (int) (y + 0.5) - 10);
                g2.draw(GameGUI.startScreen.playerHealthBar);
                g2.fill(GameGUI.startScreen.playerHealthBar);
                GameGUI.startScreen.healthBarGlyphVector = new Font("Tahoma", 0, 11).createGlyphVector(new FontRenderContext(null, true, false), String.valueOf(GameGUI.startScreen.aiHealth));
                g2.setColor(GameGUI.startScreen.aiHealthBarColor);
                g2.drawGlyphVector(GameGUI.startScreen.healthBarGlyphVector, (int) (GameGUI.gameResources.getAIRobot().getLocation().get(0).x + 40 - GameGUI.startScreen.healthBarGlyphVector.getNumGlyphs() * (double) GameGUI.startScreen.healthBarGlyphVector.getFont().getSize() / 2 + 0.5), GameGUI.gameResources.getAIRobot().getLocation().get(0).y - 20);
                GameGUI.startScreen.aiHealthBar.setLocation(GameGUI.gameResources.getAIRobot().getLocation().get(0).x, GameGUI.gameResources.getAIRobot().getLocation().get(0).y - 10);
                g2.draw(GameGUI.startScreen.aiHealthBar);
                g2.fill(GameGUI.startScreen.aiHealthBar);
                g2.setColor(tempColor);
                if(GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList != null) {
                    for(int i = GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        tempColor = g2.getColor();
                        oldTransform = g2.getTransform();
                        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
                        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                        g2.drawLine((int) (GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.get(i).getCurrentLine().getStartX() + 0.5), (int) (GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.get(i).getCurrentLine().getStartY() + 0.5), (int) (GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.get(i).getCurrentLine().getEndX() + 0.5), (int) (GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.get(i).getCurrentLine().getEndY() + 0.5));
                        g2.setTransform(oldTransform);
                        g2.setColor(tempColor);
                    }
                }
                if(GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList != null) {
                    for(int i = GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        tempColor = g2.getColor();
                        oldTransform = g2.getTransform();
                        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
                        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                        g2.drawLine((int) (GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.get(i).getCurrentLine().getStartX() + 0.5), (int) (GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.get(i).getCurrentLine().getStartY() + 0.5), (int) (GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.get(i).getCurrentLine().getEndX() + 0.5), (int) (GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.get(i).getCurrentLine().getEndY() + 0.5));
                        g2.setTransform(oldTransform);
                        g2.setColor(tempColor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else try {
            if(GameGUI.startScreen.checkGameOver() && GameGUI.startScreen.getGameOverVector() != null) {
                g2.drawGlyphVector(GameGUI.startScreen.getGameOverVector(), (int) (380 - GameGUI.startScreen.getGameOverVector().getNumGlyphs() * (double) GameGUI.startScreen.healthBarGlyphVector.getFont().getSize() / 2 + 0.5), 250 - 29);
                GameGUI.startScreen.imageList = new ArrayList <String> (Arrays.asList());
            }
        } catch (GameResourceException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GameCanvas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if((code == KeyEvent.VK_UP || code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || code == KeyEvent.VK_W || code == KeyEvent.VK_S || code == KeyEvent.VK_A || code == KeyEvent.VK_D) && keyPress && x >= 0 && x <= 680 && y >= 0 && y <= 400) {
            x += velX;
            y += velY;
            GameGUI.gameResources.getPlayerRobot().setLocation(new Point((int) (x + 0.5), (int) (y + 0.5)), new Point((int) (x + 0.5 + 37), (int) (y + 0.5 + 99)));
        }
        else {
            if(x < 0) x++;
            if(x > 680) x--;
            if(y < 0) y++;
            if(y > 400) y--;
        }
        if(GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList != null) {
            for(int i = GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                Rectangle tempRectAI = new Rectangle(GameGUI.gameResources.getAIRobot().getLocation().get(0).getLocation().x, GameGUI.gameResources.getAIRobot().getLocation().get(0).getLocation().y, GameGUI.gameResources.getAIRobot().getLocation().get(1).getLocation().x, GameGUI.gameResources.getAIRobot().getLocation().get(1).getLocation().y);
                Line line = GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.get(i).getCurrentLine();
                if(GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.get(i).getLocation().x + 50 < 0 || GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.get(i).getLocation().x > 762 || GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.get(i).getLocation().y + 50 < 0 || GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.get(i).getLocation().y > 500 || tempRectAI.intersectsLine(line.getStartX(), line.getStartY(), line.getEndX(), line.getEndY()))
                    GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.remove(i);
                else {
                    GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.get(i).move(time);
                }
            }
        }
        if(GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList != null) {
            for(int i = GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                Rectangle tempRectPlayer = new Rectangle(GameGUI.gameResources.getPlayerRobot().getLocation().get(0).getLocation().x, GameGUI.gameResources.getPlayerRobot().getLocation().get(0).getLocation().y, GameGUI.gameResources.getPlayerRobot().getLocation().get(1).getLocation().x, GameGUI.gameResources.getPlayerRobot().getLocation().get(1).getLocation().y);
                Line line = GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.get(i).getCurrentLine();
                if(GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.get(i).getLocation().x + 50 < 0 || GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.get(i).getLocation().x > 762 || GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.get(i).getLocation().y + 50 < 0 || GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.get(i).getLocation().y > 500 || tempRectPlayer.intersectsLine(line.getStartX(), line.getStartY(), line.getEndX(), line.getEndY()))
                    GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.remove(i);
                else {
                    GameGUI.gameResources.aiLaserList.get(i).move(time);
                }
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }
    public void up() {
        velY = -1.5;
        velX = 0;
    }
    public void down() {
        velY = 1.5;
        velX = 0;
    }
    public void left() {
        velX = -1.5;
        velY = 0;
    }
    public void right() {
        velX = 1.5;
        velY = 0;
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        keyPress = true;
        code = e.getKeyCode();
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP || code == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            up();
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            down();
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || code == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            right();
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || code == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            left();
        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        keyPress = false;
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
        mousePoint = evt.getPoint();
        if(GameGUI.getGameOver()) GameGUI.gameResources.resetForNextLevel();
        else {
            GameGUI.gameResources.getPlayerRobot().setLocation(new Point((int) (x + 0.5), (int) (y + 0.5)), new Point((int) (x + 0.5 + 37), (int) (y + 0.5 + 99)));
            Rectangle tempR = new Rectangle(GameGUI.gameResources.getPlayerRobot().getLocation().get(0).x, GameGUI.gameResources.getPlayerRobot().getLocation().get(0).y, GameGUI.gameResources.getPlayerRobot().getLocation().get(1).x, GameGUI.gameResources.getPlayerRobot().getLocation().get(1).y);
            GameGUI.gameResources.playerLaserList.add(new Laser(new Point((int) (tempR.getCenterX() + 0.5), (int) (tempR.getCenterY() + 0.5)), evt.getPoint(), GameGUI.gameResources));
        }
    }
}
```

Laser:

```
package application;

import java.awt.Point;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class Laser {

    private Point point1;
    private Point point2;
    private Point currentPoint;
    private double angle;
    private Line laserLine;
    private Point farEnd;
    private Point farStart;
    private double x1, x2, y1, y2, m, y3, x3;
    private GameResources gameResources;

    public Laser(Point tempPoint1, Point tempPoint2, GameResources tempGR) {
        gameResources = tempGR;
        currentPoint = point1 = tempPoint1;
        point2 = tempPoint2;
        double leg1 = point2.x - point1.x;
        double leg2 = point2.y - point1.y;
        double hyp = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(leg1, 2) + Math.pow(leg2, 2));
        angle = Math.asin(leg2 / hyp);
        if(angle < 0) angle = 2 * Math.abs(angle);
        farEnd = getPointX(460);
        farStart = getPointX(0);
        laserLine = new Line(farStart.x, farStart.y, farEnd.x, farStart.y);
        x1 = tempPoint1.x;
        y1 = tempPoint1.y;
        x2 = tempPoint2.x;
        y2 = tempPoint2.y;
        m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
        x3 = 0;
        y3 = 0;
    }

    public Point getInitialLocation() {
        return point1;
    }
    public Point getLocation() {
        return currentPoint;
    }
    public double getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }
    public Line getLine() {
        return laserLine;
    }
    public Line getCurrentLine() {
        Line currentLine = new Line();
        if(getAngle() < Math.PI && getAngle() > 0)
            currentLine = new Line((int) (currentPoint.x + 0.5), (int) (currentPoint.y + 0.5), (int) (getPointX((int) (currentPoint.y + 0.5) + (int) (Math.sin(angle) * 50 + 0.5)).x + 0.5), (int) (currentPoint.y + 0.5) + (int) (Math.sin(angle) * 50 + 0.5));
        else if(getAngle() > Math.PI && getAngle() < 2 * Math.PI)
            currentLine = new Line((int) (currentPoint.x + 0.5), (int) (currentPoint.y + 0.5), (int) (getPointX((int) (currentPoint.y + 0.5) - (int) (Math.sin(angle) * 50 + 0.5)).x + 0.5), (int) (currentPoint.y + 0.5) - (int) (Math.sin(angle) * 50 + 0.5));
        System.out.println(currentLine.getStartX() + " " + currentLine.getStartY() + " " + point1);
        return currentLine;
    }
    public void setLocation(Point tempLocation) {
        currentPoint = tempLocation;
    }

    public Point getPointY(int x) {
        if(x1 == x2 && y1 != y2) return null;
        else if(m < 0) y3 = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) * (double) x - (x2 * ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) - y2);
        else if(m > 0) y3 = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) * (double) x + (x2 * ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) - y2);
        else if(m == 0) y3 = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) * (double) x;
        return new Point(x, (int) (y3 + 0.5));
    }
    public Point getPointX(int y) {
        if(x1 == x2 && y1 != y2) return new Point((int) (x1 + 0.5), y);
        else if(m < 0) x3 = ((double) y + (x2 * ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) - y2)) / ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
        else if(m > 0) x3 = ((double) y - (x2 * ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) - y2)) / ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
        else if(m == 0) x3 = (double) y / (((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)));
        return new Point((int) (x3 + 0.5), (int) (y + 0.5));
    }
    public Line move(double time) {
        //old algorithm
        /*double x = 0, y = 0;
        if(y2 > y1) {
            y = currentPoint.y + gameResources.getLaserSpeed() * time;
            currentPoint = getPointX((int) y);
        }
        else if(y2 < y1) {
            y = currentPoint.y - gameResources.getLaserSpeed() * time;
            currentPoint = getPointX((int) y);
        }
        else if(y2 == y1 && x2 > x1) {
            x = currentPoint.x + gameResources.getLaserSpeed() * time;
            currentPoint = getPointY((int) x);
        }
        else if(y2 == y1 && x2 < x1) {
            x = currentPoint.x - gameResources.getLaserSpeed() * time;
            currentPoint = getPointY((int) x);
        }*/

        //new algorithm
        if(getAngle() < Math.PI / 2 && getAngle() > 0) {
            System.out.println("(1) First quad");
            setLocation(getPointY((int) (getLocation().x + 1 + 0.5)));
        }
        else if(getAngle() < Math.PI && getAngle() > Math.PI / 2) {
            System.out.println("(2) Second quad");
            setLocation(getPointY((int) (getLocation().x - 1 - 0.5)));
        }
        else if(getAngle() > Math.PI && getAngle() < 3 * Math.PI / 2) {
            System.out.println("(3) Third quad");
            setLocation(getPointY((int) (getLocation().x - 1 - 0.5)));
        }
        else if(getAngle() > 3 * Math.PI / 2 && getAngle() < 2 * Math.PI) {
            System.out.println("(4) Fourth quad");
            setLocation(getPointY((int) (getLocation().x + 1 + 0.5)));
        }
        else if(getAngle() == 2 * Math.PI || getAngle() == 0)
            setLocation(new Point((int) (getLocation().x + 1 + 0.5), (int) (getLocation().y + 0.5)));
        else if(getAngle() == Math.PI)
            setLocation(new Point((int) (getLocation().x - 1 - 0.5), (int) (getLocation().y + 0.5)));
        else if(getAngle() == Math.PI / 2)
            setLocation(new Point((int) (getLocation().x + 0.5), (int) (getLocation().y + 1 + 0.5)));
        else if(getAngle() == 3 * Math.PI / 2)
            setLocation(new Point((int) (getLocation().x + 0.5), (int) (getLocation().y - 1 - 0.5)));
        return getCurrentLine();
    }
    public void setGameResources(GameResources tempGR) {
        gameResources = tempGR;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you would get more response if you would simply reduce your question to a one or two sentences with a tenth of the code. Reducing your problem is also a good way to get to the core of the issue. If you have multiple questions simple ask multiple smaller questions.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the feedback!